# How to retrieve data from different parent nodes in a Firebase Database in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I have the following database:

[image]

I want to retrieve the value of name given a specific ID value in JavaScript.

Right now I have the following code, but it doesnt seem to acces both ID and name nodes:

```
var user = db.ref("Users").orderByChild("ID").equalTo("12345");
       
        users.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the code below:

```
var ref = db.ref("Users").orderByChild("ID/value").equalTo("12345");
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            
        var name = childData.name.value;
    });
});
```